# if CPT content is empty then

Tags: posts, the-content

I need to be able to do something if the content is empty in a CPT. This works for standard WP posts using the following:

```
if($post->post_content=="") {

//Do something if there is content is empty  

} else {

//Do something if there is content is NOT empty

}
```

How can I amend this to refer to a CPT as well as a standard post?

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried this with a CPT? It should work with that code, CPT's and posts are the same, they just have a post type field that's different, but they're handled and stored the same way

Comment: Yeah, I am using the same code via get_template_part() function. It works on pages but not on my CPT posts. I thought it may be down to the post type.

Comment: I'd check to make sure there is a $post object at this point in the CPT. Maybe your queries are set up differently in the CPT than the default single.php. You could also try changing the conditional to `if(empty($post->post_content))` in case there are blank spaces or something odd like that.

Comment: agreed, really these kinds of checks should be inside the main post loop